# Django save() method not saving to DB

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

What am I doing wrong?

I have two tables, `User` and `Entrepreneur`. Objects are not saving in the `Entrepreneur` table. I even used the shell!

I've deleted the DB and migration files and the error stays the same.

I know similar questions have been asked but I found none fitting my situation.

**MY MODELS:**

```
class EntrepreneurProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    location = CountryField(blank=True, null=True)
    email_notif_on = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    skills = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    accomplishnment = models.ForeignKey(Accomplishment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    portfolio = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.SlugField(unique=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.url:
            self.url = slugify(f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} {str(uuid.uuid4()[:7])}')
```

**MY VIEWS:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        user_form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            entrep = EntrepreneurProfile.objects.create(user=user)
            entrep.save()

            print(entrep.id)
            return redirect('users:login')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreateForm()
        data = {'user_form': user_form}
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you forgot to call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` in your `save` method as it is mentioned in 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods